Cannot access distro after running sudo apt dist-upgrade
Turned on dual boot laptop yesterday after some time away and ran sudo apt dist-upgrade on Bodhi and Kali. Bodhi ran fine. Kali left me with a blank screen and flashing cursor in the upper left corner. I hard reset the laptop and booted into Kali recovery and got the attached message. When I hit enter at the end it takes me back to the blank screen. My network sees Kali from the blank screen, but when I try to ssh in it says connection refused. Really appreciate any advice. Thank you!


Did you hit Enter and try the journalctl -xb command as instructed? Basically the only errors shown on the screen are network time sync errors, which should not be boot stopping errors.

Yes.  Enter takes me back to the blank screen.
